# Laravel 5.5 error InvalidArgumentException: No hint path defined for [core]. in file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-5.5

I have recently migrate laravel 4.2 app to 5.0. After spending a lot of time fixing issues I encountered this error whenever I used to call APIs Authenticated or not

> ( Larvel 5.5 error InvalidArgumentException: No hint path defined for
>   [core]. in file. )

This error made me upgrade from laravel 5.0 to 5.1 and 5.2 to 5.3 and finally upgraded to 5.5. All other screens and routes are working perfectly fine.

This is an example problematic route

> Route::get('/org/getname',  'OrgController@getName' );

In the controller, I am just returning a dummy JSON.

If I change it to post. I get page inactivity error.

I am stuck with this error as every other aspect of the application is working fine except this.

Comment: Would you send code inside your controller?

Comment: Thanks for the response @DmitriyButeiko

I had created a dummy controller in the migrated project to figure if i can replicate the issue and it is happening
`
class OrgController extends Controller {
 


  public function getName(){
    return response()->json([
    'name' => 'Abigail',
    'state' => 'CA'
  ]);
  }
}`

Comment: How are you making the call to `/org/getname`?

Comment: Route::get('/test/c',  'OrgController@getName' );

Currently testing it in browser as a get request and PostMan too